# Macbook Air - fonts not aliased on external monitor

Tags: mac, display, anti-aliasing, macbook-air

I have 2010 Macbook Air 11", which is connected via DisplayPort to HP LP2475w LCD monitor. Unfortunately the text displayed on the external monitor has rough edges and as far as I can tell, it is not anti-aliased at all.

I searched for a solution and the one most commonly offered, [such as here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090828224632809), did not work for me. For the record, it says to run this command in the terminal:

```
defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing -int 2
```

Any other options?